# What does the loop integral of geodesic curvature intuitively mean in the absence of a surface normal?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology, big-picture

The geodesic curvature $k_g$ can be interpreted as the rate of rotation of the tangent vector about the surface normal, as discussed in [this article](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Geodesic_curvature). The article goes on to say that the integral $\int k_g$ gives the **total rotation**, which I intuitively understand as the number of times a curve's tangent winds around the normal with respect to the curve itself.

Now, in some physics problems, we are forced to work with an intrinsic picture and so cannot think of a surface normal. While the geometry may be studied in these cases using Christoffel symbols, Gauss-Bonnet, etc, I am lacking an intuitive understanding of what the **line integral of the geodesic curvature** might mean in terms of rotation of the tangent vector (or some other qualitative picture). Is there such a simple geometric picture?

Comment: Yes, the normal is irrelevant. This all makes sense intrinsically. It tells you (for small curves) how much a vector turns when parallel translated around the curve. See section 3.1 of my differential geometry text, linked in my profile.

Comment: @TedShifrin, thank you. Your notes answered my question.

Comment: Great. Glad they're useful to you!!

Comment: Have you heard about Frenet and Darboux mobile frames ?

Comment: @JeanMarie yes I have, but I thought that we won’t have a normal vector here